# Display the name of a column in a gridview cell tooltip ASP.net/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dynamic GridView1 with AutogenerateFields set to TRUE. The following code will display the value of the cell in a GridView but what I need for it to do is to display the column name when you hover over a cell. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[i].ToolTip = GridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText;
        }

    }

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        foreach (TableCell gvcell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            gvcell.ToolTip = gvcell.Text;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just updated the code. I had an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this snippet. You can loop all the cell on the `OnRowDataBound` event and get the header text from the `HeaderRow`.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //loop all cells in the row
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            //set the tooltip text to be the header text
            e.Row.Cells[i].ToolTip = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick question VDWWD, how would I reference ColumnName : RowName in a tooltip?

Comment: You mean like this? `e.Row.Cells[i].ToolTip = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text + " : Row " + i;`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `RowName`

Comment: Exactly, except instead e.Row.Cells[i].Text I used e.Row.Cells[1].Text. Thank you so much!

Comment: VDWWD, how do you hide a tooltip if cell's value is NULL?

Comment: `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.Cells[i].Text)) { //show tooltip }`

Comment: if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //loop all cells in the row
            for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                if (e.Row.Cells[i].Text == "x")
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[i].ToolTip = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[i].ToolTip = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text + " : " + e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
                }
            }
        }

Comment: I am trying to hide tooltips where the value is "x" otherwise show the tooltip

Answer (score 1):

Thats pretty simple , i wonder why u want to show tooltip when u have column name as headertext.bdw here u go.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ToolTip="Category" ID="lblCategory" Text='<%#Eval("Category") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sub Category">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ToolTip="SubCategory" ID="lblSubCategory" Text='<%#Eval("SubCategory") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I have an unknown amount of columns that are being generated from a stored procedure. I was wondering if there a C# way of doing displaying the column name in a tooltip. I don't want to hardcode column names